# Get the sorted elements using pre-computed sort only

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, sorting

Looking for the following algorithm.

Given for example the following unordered list:

```
main_list = np.array([100,200,400,1000,800,900,700,600,500,300])
```

and given the query list elements `q = np.array([2,5,7,9])`, that correspond to the list `np.array([400, 900, 600, 300])`, get directly the sorted elements from main_list and the sorted positions

```
np.array([300, 400, 600, 900])
np.array([9,2,7,5])
```

The main condition: use only pre-computed sorted arrays, to avoid sorting operation each time I get a new query.

EDIT: Solution in numpy (thanks @cary-swoveland!)

Firt pre-compute the sorted of sorted arguments. This is offline step:

```
argsort = np.argsort(main_list)
argsort_argsort = np.argsort(argsort)
```

Then at query time:

```
q = np.array([2,5,7,9])

new_array = np.full(main_list.shape[0], -1)
new_array[argsort_argsort[q]] = q

sorted_q = new_array[new_array != -1]
sorted_values = main_list[sorted_q]

print(sorted_q)
print(sorted_values)
```

results:

```
[9 2 7 5]
[300 400 600 900]
```

Comment: Isn't this just asking for you to sort the list, then return the values at the query indices? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Sorting the result is certainly mandatory here (possibly just the indices), since the result needs at least to be to be reordered compared to the query indices. The sort can be optimized though.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer, not an edit to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution in Ruby, which I expect could be converted to other languages fairly easily.

We are given the following.

```
arr = [100, 200, 400, 1000, 800, 900, 700, 600, 500, 300]
```

**Step 1: Produce an array containing sorted indices of `arr`**

```
a = arr.each_index.sort_by { |i| arr[i] }
  #=> [0, 1, 9, 2, 8, 7, 6, 4, 5, 3]
```

This means that

```
arr[a[i]] = arr.sort[i]
```

If `i = 2`, for example,

```
arr[a[2]] #=> arr[9] => 300
arr.sort[2] = 300
```

**Step 2: Create an array of orderings of offsets**

```
b = (0..arr.size-1).sort_by { |i| a[i] }
  #=> [0, 1, 3, 9, 7, 8, 6, 5, 4, 2]
```

`b[2] #=> 3` means that `arr[2] = arr.sort[3]`.

**Step 3: Construct the desired arrays for each given array of indices**

The time complexity of this operation is O(n), n being the size of the array.

Suppose

```
indices = [2,5,7,9]
```

so

```
arr.values_at(*indices)
  #=> [400, 900, 600, 300]
```

First create an array containing `arr.size` elements, all of which equal `nil`.

```
c = Array.new(arr.size)
  #=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
```

Now replace elements of `c` with elements of `indices` in the correct locations.

```
indices.each { |idx| c[b[idx]] = idx }

c #=> [nil, nil, 9, 2, nil, 7, nil, nil, 5, nil]
```

Lastly, remove the `nil` elements.

```
c.compact
  #=> [9, 2, 7, 5]
```

and

```
arr.values_at(*c)
  #=> [300, 400, 600, 900]
```

---

Similarly, if

```
indices = [5, 3, 1, 7, 2]
```

then

```
arr.values_at(*indices)
  #=> [900, 1000, 200, 600, 400]
c = Array.new(arr.size)
  #=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
indices.each { |idx| c[b[idx]] = idx }
c #=> [nil,   1, nil,   2, nil,   7, nil, nil,   5,   3]
d = c.compact
  #=> [1, 2, 7, 5, 3]
arr.values_at(*d)
  #=> [200, 400, 600, 900, 1000]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of size and positions like:

[[400,2],[900,5],[600,7],[300,9]]

Then sort and write the positions in the result array.